# Batch file - Loop thru folder and get file name

Tags: batch-file, bcp

Sorry if this seems like a simple question, but I could not find the right answer anywhere....

I have a set of files in a folder with this naming convention....
tablename_date_time.dat

I need to loop thru the folder and extract the tablename (up to the underscore) and use it in a bcp command, what would be the best way to do this?

So far I have the command, but I can't figure out the substr part.

```
for /f %%i in (%1) do (
    bcp tablename IN C:\temp\%%i_.dat -n -T
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, do not use abbreviations!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop)

Comment: @Penn - Not a duplicate of that; the user is looking for a way to parse out _part_ of the file name.

Comment: @Penn May I ask what abbreviations you are referring to?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin OK, sounds like he wants a regex. Can't find any docs on how though...

Comment: @Steve "Thru", in the question and title.

Comment: It does look like a regular expression is needed, though depending on how the tablenames are included, it may be possible to use a numeric substring. There is useful information on taking substrings by position and length (rather than character matching) at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html); beyond that, third-party regular-expression software - `grep` or `awk` are the most likely candidates - will be needed. (Alternatively, the batch file can be completely replaced by a PowerShell script, if the querent finds this acceptable.)

Comment: Or a cmd that creates a VBScript, runs it and deletes it again, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790213/5509575)

Comment: Maybe `for /F "delims=_" %%G in ("%%~i") do bcp %%G IN C:\temp\%%i_.dat -n -T`. Hard to answer without knowing `%1`. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].